# Memcached Client getStats list of keys for the possible stats?

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

MemcachedClient has a [getStats](http://dustin.github.com/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient.html#getStats%28java.lang.String%29) method which accepts a String key for the stat value. Is there a list of possible keys I can use?

Also is this a local operation or a blocking call to server to get those stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that params for getStats are the same used when you "telnet" your memcache. You can find stats command args here: http://lzone.de/articles/memcached.htm

options are: slabs, malloc, items, detail, sizes, reset.

I don't know if it's a blocking call, but i dont think so.

hope this will help,

cheers.

Comment: There is also details about stats command here: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands#Statistics

Comment: this list is not comprehensive